# Django - Ensure 2 fields in a table of the same model type don't have the same value for an entity

Tags: python, django, relational-database

So I have a user class and a user can follow another user, but I don't want the user to be able to follow themselves. Is there a way to add this constraint to Django?

```
class FollowUser(AbstractSimpleModel):
    follower_id = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='follower_id')
    followee_id = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='followee_id')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you need to validate the field's value based on other field's value, here being `FollowUser.follower_id` and `FollowUser.followee_id`, you may follow this process of how Django handles [validation of fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/instances/#validating-objects) by:

1. Implement [Model.clean()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.clean) where you would run the validation
2. Override [Model.save()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.save) to call the complete validation process via `Model.full_clean()`. This explicit step is needed because as documented:

   > Note that full_clean() will not be called automatically when you call
   > your model’s save() method. You’ll need to call it manually when you
   > want to run one-step model validation for your own manually created
   > models. For example:

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from django.db import models


class UserDummy(models.Model):
    pass

class FollowUser(models.Model):
    follower_id = models.ForeignKey(UserDummy, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='follower_id')
    followee_id = models.OneToOneField(UserDummy, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='followee_id')

    def clean(self):
        if self.follower_id == self.followee_id:
            raise ValidationError("Users can't follow themselves")

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.full_clean()
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

### Sample Run

Setup the data:

```
>>> from my_app.models import *
>>> UserDummy.objects.values()
<QuerySet [{'id': 1}, {'id': 2}, {'id': 3}]>
>>> user1 = UserDummy.objects.get(id=1)
>>> user2 = UserDummy.objects.get(id=2)
>>> user3 = UserDummy.objects.get(id=3)
```

Failed validation:

```
>>> # Using Model.save()
>>> FollowUser(follower_id=user1, followee_id=user1).save()
Traceback (most recent call last):
    raise ValidationError(errors)
django.core.exceptions.ValidationError: {'__all__': ["Users can't follow themselves"]}
>>> 
>>> # Using Model.objects.create()
>>> FollowUser.objects.create(follower_id=user1, followee_id=user1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
    raise ValidationError(errors)
django.core.exceptions.ValidationError: {'__all__': ["Users can't follow themselves"]}
```

Successful validation:

```
>>> # Using Model.save()
>>> FollowUser(follower_id=user1, followee_id=user2).save()
>>> 
>>> # Using Model.objects.create()
>>> FollowUser.objects.create(follower_id=user2, followee_id=user3)
<FollowUser: FollowUser object (2)>
>>> 
>>> FollowUser.objects.values()
<QuerySet [{'id': 1, 'follower_id_id': 1, 'followee_id_id': 2}, {'id': 2, 'follower_id_id': 2, 'followee_id_id': 3}]>
```

---

Note: Be aware that if ever you are using [Model.objects.bulk_create()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create), you would need further changes as it doesn't call the `Model.save()` functionality as documented:

> **bulk_create()**
>
> The model’s save() method will not be called, and the pre_save and
> post_save signals will not be sent.